# How to fix this race condition in Objective C / async problem? 'index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

Tags: objective-c, obd-ii

Hi i have a Problem with this Library: 
LTSupportAutomotive

I´m a swift programmer so not really good in objective c.

how to fix this race condition?

I hope someone can help me.

'*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'

```
-(void)asyncEnqueueInternalCommand:(LTOBD2AdapterInternalCommand*)internalCommand
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        [_commandQueue addObject:internalCommand];
    }
}
```

Source code:

https://github.com/mickeyl/LTSupportAutomotive/blob/f51b962421f211ee6af5c733f79190117d7cac5e/LTSupportAutomotive/LTOBD2Adapter.m

**UPDATE 1:**

Created a branch with the first fixes:
https://github.com/Skyb0rg/LTSupportAutomotive/tree/BugfixMemoryManagement

After adding additional commandQueue i got new errors:

in LTBTLEWriteCharacteristicStream.m

```
-(void)characteristicDidWriteValue
{
    [self.delegate stream:self handleEvent:NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable];
}
```

this function is crashing with:
Selector name found in current argument registers: delegate

Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00000001bcc19430 objc_retain + 16

1   LTSupportAutomotive                  0x00000001093c2a34 -[LTBTLEWriteCharacteristicStream characteristicDidWriteValue] (LTBTLEWriteCharacteristicStream.m:39)

2   LTSupportAutomotive                  0x00000001093c2714 -[LTBTLESerialTransporter peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:] (LTBTLESerialTransporter.m:311)

3   CoreBluetooth                        0x00000001c35e6ce0 -[CBPeripheral handleAttributeEvent:args:attributeSelector:delegateSelector:delegateFlag:] + 236

4   CoreBluetooth                        0x00000001c35e6e40 -[CBPeripheral handleCharacteristicEvent:characteristicSelector:delegateSelector:delegateFlag:] + 128

5   CoreBluetooth                        0x00000001c35e24f0 -[CBPeripheral handleMsg:args:] + 352

6   CoreBluetooth                        0x00000001c35dcbfc -[CBCentralManager handleMsg:args:] + 200

7   CoreBluetooth                        0x00000001c35eb770 __30-[CBXpcConnection _handleMsg:]_block_invoke + 56

8   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd4696c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20

9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd46a484 _dispatch_client_callout + 12

10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd411bd0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 588

11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd41274c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 480

12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd411a9c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280

13  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd412718 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 428

14  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd41aeb8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596

15  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001bd64d0dc _pthread_wqthread + 308

16  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001bd64fcec start_wqthread + 0

**and another crash in**: LTBTLEReadCharacteristicStream.m

```
-(void)characteristicDidUpdateValue
{
        NSData* value = _characteristic.value;
        [_buffer appendData:value];
        [self.delegate stream:self handleEvent:NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable];
}
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OS_dispatch_data stream:handleEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281be1b90'

Thread 9 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x00000001bd5c7104 __pthread_kill + 8

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001bd643020 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 376

2   libsystem_c.dylib                    0x00000001bd51ed78 abort + 136

3   VW-R-CLUB Member APP                 0x00000001045603ac uncaught_exception_handler + 68

4   CoreFoundation                       0x00000001bda321e0 __handleUncaughtException + 688

5   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00000001bcc01e4c _objc_terminate() + 108

6   VW-R-CLUB Member APP                 0x0000000104555c4c BITCrashUncaughtCXXTerminateHandler() (BITCrashCXXExceptionHandler.mm:183)

7   libc++abi.dylib                      0x00000001bcbf50fc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12

8   libc++abi.dylib                      0x00000001bcbf5188 std::terminate() + 80

9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd46a498 _dispatch_client_callout + 32

10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd411bd0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 588

11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd41274c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 480

12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd411a9c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280

13  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd412718 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 428

14  libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001bd41aeb8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596

15  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001bd64d0dc _pthread_wqthread + 308

16  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001bd64fcec start_wqthread + 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the code you show is not the one to be found in github. Do you synchronize all usages of `_commandQueue`, or only this one? If only this one, why aren't the others synchronized?

Then, in github I find multiple usages of `_commandQueue`, some of them in methods that are named `async`..., but also some not `async`, like `cancelPendingCommands` or `responseCompleted`. You need to find out what is the intention of `async` in a method name, and why methods like `cancelPendingCommands` is not somehow `async`.

---

## Update

So the main idea seems to protect all `_commandQueue` accesses inside the serial `_dispatchQueue`. This is already the case in the `async`... methods: They are called from within that queue:

```
dispatch_async( _dispatchQueue, ^{
    [self asyncEnqueueInternalCommand:internalCommand];
});
```

So you need to ensure that *every* access to `_commandQueue` is enqueued in this queue, e.g. change `cancelPendingCommands` to something like

```
-(void)cancelPendingCommands
{
    dispatch_async( _dispatchQueue, ^{
        // This cancels all but the first command in order to prevent sending a new command while
        // the response to an active command is still pending. OBD2 adapters usually can't cope with
        // that and emit a 'STOPPED' response in that case.
        if ( _hasPendingAnswer )
        {
            NSRange allButTheFirst = NSMakeRange( 1, _commandQueue.count - 1 );
            [_commandQueue removeObjectsInRange:allButTheFirst];
        }
        else
        {
            [_commandQueue removeAllObjects];
        }
    });
}
```

(or create a dedicated `asyncCancelPendingCommands` function, that will be called from `cancelPendingCommands` from inside a dispatch block. And so on.

P.S. If you need synchronous execution, you could also use `dispatch_sync` instead of `dispatch_async`, but then you have to ensure that you do not create deadlocks.

Comment: Hi Andreas, it was only a test with "@synchronized".
I´m not shure what the right solution is.

i have 2 other methods with a serial queue.
but i dont know how to solve the crashes.

The master is github. what are the first steps to the solution?
In swift it would be easier to me, but in objective c i am totally lost.

Comment: I think the `_dispatchQueue` is what you want; please check my updated answer

Comment: OK added the _dispatchQueue in cancelPendingCommands and in responseCompleted. Also removed @synchronized. I will test it the next days.

Comment: OK tested it today and got a new error: 
[_commandQueue removeObjectsInRange:allButTheFirst]; -> Results in :

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectsInRange:]: range {0, 1} extends beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: And you are absolutely sure that the _commandQueue is not empty when you call `removeObjectsInRange`? Because the error message sound this way...

Comment: no i was not sure.
Just added the following code:
if ( self->_commandQueue.count > 0 ) {
                NSRange allButTheFirst = NSMakeRange( 1, self->_commandQueue.count - 1 );
                [self->_commandQueue removeObjectsInRange:allButTheFirst];
            }

Comment: will test it tomorrow again with a track of 180km.

Comment: Don´t have new results ... fixed additional bugs. But the first error didn´t happend again. Sometimes the bug only happens once in 100.000 responses.
Will update here next week.

Comment: i got new crashes today in small obd recodings. maybee you can help me. I have Updated the question.

Comment: created a new branch for the memory errors: https://github.com/Skyb0rg/LTSupportAutomotive/tree/BugfixMemoryManagement

Comment: Seems to be some memory problems that have been caused by the GCD calls (memory of e.g. the delegate already being freed before access). Maybe you should try `dispatch_sync` instead of `dispatch_async`.

Comment: OK i will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that the two serial queues transporter and adapter, both are created seperately needs to be the same? now they where executed concurrently.

Comment: If you access the same resource, you need to use one and only one mutex object (e.g. dispatch queue). Maybe it will be helpful if you create (and upload) a full contained, stand-alone test project (that does not need any hardware etc.) which can reproduce the issues.

Comment: Did some tests and the single global serial dispatch queue seems to work. Not 100% sure, but the last 2 days i had no more crashes.

A stand-alone test project without hardware ist not possible. You need a car and dongle and many different circumstances, the data is never the same. the readings are like an old serial bus with hex bit-blocks. To emulate that it would need many months. 

i will told you if something will change. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Today another crash in the same functions. But now its it less often.
I will have to take a look at the  SerialTransporter.m File. The serial queue is only used for the manager there.

Comment: Yep. It seems you need to investigate a lot to encapsulate all multi-threaded-usages into mutexes. I wonder why and how the software was running before? Did you introduce multithreading just recently?

Comment: Its a public api i installed with cocoapod and no created by me.
i used it since 3 months in my App (Beta) and hat ohny a few issues.
But now i use it permanentl, before only to check the current values.
Multithreading was introduced by the creator Dr. Michael Lauer.

Comment: Now it works :)
The delegate was created with __unsafe_unretained not weak.
Created a pull request at:
https://github.com/mickeyl/LTSupportAutomotive/pull/26

Thank your for you help!!!